# suggests that she sit /sits/sat

Tags: grammar, tense, subordinate-clauses

I have a question about "The verbs with the general meaning of suggestion and form of verbs"

> a) She declined a seat beside Charles on the sofa. She insisted that Jane **sit** there. (subjunctive verb)
>
> b) She declined a seat beside Charles on the sofa. She insisted that Jane **sits** there.(indicative verb)
>
> c) She declined a seat beside Charles on the sofa. She insisted that Jane **sat** there.

sentence a and sentence b are grammatically correct in my opinion but I am not sure about sentence c. is sentence c grammatically and idiomatically correct?

I have seen a sentence in this structure (sentence c) in a website but I have not seen somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a., but I wouldn't blink if I heard somebody say c. But b. is very odd - the tenses don't match.

Comment: All three are possible, I think, if (with some effort) you imagine the right context, e.g. *"She insisted that Jane (normally) **sits** there (so she would not take Jane's customary place)"*.  But I'm not sure if that properly answers OP's question.

Comment: I think  three of the sentences are correct grammatically but they have different meanings.
sentence 1 and sentence 2 are in the same meaning but sentence 3 has different meaning.
sentence 1 and sentence 2  can be made in a context  like this
''jane was told to sit there''
but in which concept sentence 3 can be used?
İs senetence c  used in a context like this.?
Someone else is telling that jane sat there.
She did not tell jane to sit there, she is just talking about jane and telling someoneelse that jane sat there
Am I right?

Comment: No, @ullas84, I think you're misunderstanding. Yes, they are all three grammatical, but b. is strange because of sequence of tenses. a. is normal for people who use the so-called subjunctive 'sit', which is effectively tenseless. When not using the subjunctive, English backshifts its tenses, so the past tense "insisted" requires a past tense "sat" in the object clause. b. only makes sense, as Andrew pointed out, with a habitual meaning for "sits".

Comment: Let me ask it in an other way.
in situation 1 , I want to say that I told jane, I insisted her  to buy a golden neckle ,I would say it in this way ; I insisted that jane buys a golden neckle 
in situation 2 If I tell someone else about jane and try to convince that person that jane bought a golden neckle (I have no effect on the fact that jane bought a golden neckle, I am just telling someone else about the fact that jane bought a golden neckle). As you see this sentence can have 2 different meanings. it means the sentence is ambigious by itself and can mean differently depending on context?

Comment: and in situance 2 I would say in the same way as in situation 1.

''I insisted that jane buys a golden neckle.''

suggestig 2 different situations with the same sentence .

Comment: Both Andrew and I have told you that a present tense ('sits' and hence 'buys') in the object clause of a past-tense verb 'insisted' is anomalous, and only makes sense with a habitual reading. But yes, "I insisted that something happen**ed**" with a past tense is ambiguous between "I made it happen" and "I was determined that somebody accept that it had happened". The "subjunctive" form ("I insisted that something happen") is not ambiguous in that way.